# messy code in Response body

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, websphere

Websphere 8559

java1.8

Eclipse Oxygen

I started a server,and tried to access the target page. And I tested in DOM Explorer,an error occured.

Error 404: java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: æ¾ä¸å°æä»¶ï¼/ds/dsc

At the begining, I think it's the problem of language of system. So I changed the language and tried again. It's not okey.
Then I tried to check the files in \workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\ds . All files are ok. But the problem still exist.
Does anyone have any suggestions about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Check your project is build correctly and it was successful. Then check the character encoding.